# How to convert Dropbox api curl to Wix fetch?

Tags: curl, velo

I use Dropbox API to upload file but I don't know how to convert cURL to Wix fetch.
Here's Dropbox API cURL:

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer " \
    --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/Homework/math/Matrices.txt\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false,\"strict_conflict\": false}" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
    --data-binary @local_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

i am considering the file as an image and writing this

```js
fetch('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',{
  method:"post",
  body: blob,
  headers:{
    "Content-Type":"application/octet-stream",
    "Authorization":"Bearer "+"<your token>",
    "Dropbox-API-Arg": JSON.stringify({
      "path":"/uploads/demo.jpg",
      "mode":"add",
      "autorename":true,
      "mute":false,
      "strict_conflict": false
      })
    }
  }).then(response=>response.json())
      .then(result=>console.log(result))
    .catch(error=>console.error);
```